# Chartjs - doughnut custom tooltipTemplate value update

Tags: chart.js

I'm having a chart build with ChartJS. On click, I need to update value and increase certain value and modify displayed colors. What I get in the console is - value gets updated, but It doesn't change color and value in tooltip doesn't change?

```
tooltipTemplate: '<span class="val"><%= value %>%</span> <span class="desc"><%= label %></span>'
```

Here's an inline link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjovicic/sg4r91bd/10/)

And after the third click, everything fails.